# Javascript adding one to counter then displaying after certain event happening

Tags: javascript

I have this peace of JS that is based on a guessing game where the computer picks random number and the user tries to guess the number. The program will give the user hints and show users' best guesses. What I would like to do is as follows: Each time one of these 3 if sentences is output, I want it to add one to a counter.  When the last sentence is output, I want the program to display how many guesses were made.

```
    if(guess < to guess){
    document.getElementById('hint').innerHTML = "The number you are trying to 
    guess is higher";
    document.getElementById('lower').innerHTML = "Best lower guess at the moment " + 
    guess;

    }else if(guess > to guess){
    document.getElementById('hint').innerHTML = "The number you are trying to 
    guess is lower";
    document.getElementById('higher').innerHTML = "Best higher guess at the 
    moment " + guess;

    }else if(guess == to guess){
    document.getElementById('hint').innerHTML = "congratulations! You guessed the right number " + " 
     right number was " + to guess + "<br>"+ "How many guesses it took ";
    document.getElementById('lower').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('higher').innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Please. Add. Some. Punctuation. Marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incrementing a number is quite easy, simply store a variable called `numberOfGuesses`:

`var numberOfGuesses = 0`

and you can increment it by 1 like this:

`numberOfGuesses += 1`

You can use this to continually increment the number of guesses by 1 until you are ready to finish and display that number.

Comment: You can also do `numberOfGuesses++` to increment by one.

Comment: @Pablo it's better to use `+=` - https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-plusplus

Comment: @Kekkosolut if this worked for you please accept it as the answer! Thanks